# Eclipse plugin for Smart GWT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, smartgwt

How cann I create "Hello world Application" in Eclipse using Smart GWT?

Is there any plug in for Eclipse for Smart GWT? If yes then how can we install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://jellebeuselinck.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/setting-up-smartgwt/) was very useful to get me started with smartGWT. It presents a small guide in setting up eclipse to program SmartGWT and how to make a small first project.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the original GWT events with:

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickHandler;
```

I found that I had to run IE 9.0 in compatibility mode to have the button working, it works fine in Chrome though, so hopefully they will sort this out soon.